# Why is Firebase not getting identifier after signing in with Apple?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement sign in with apple with Firebase in my NextJS app. The problem I am having is that after the user signs in I see them signed up in firebase but they have no identifier.

Right before the user signs in I get a runtime error saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')
```

Which means that for some reason it is catching an error before getting redirected back to the app. I think this may be the source of the issue.

This is my signInWithRedirect and getRedirectResult

```
const Login = ({ }) => {
  const loginWithApple = () => {
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)
    getRedirectResult(auth)
    .then((result) => {
      const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      if (credential) {
        // You can also get the Apple OAuth Access and ID Tokens.
        const accessToken = credential.accessToken;
        const idToken = credential.idToken;
      }
      // The signed-in user info.
      const user = result.user;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      // The email of the user's account used.
      const email = error.customData.email;
      // The credential that was used.
      const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);

      // ...
    });
  }
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      spacing={0}
      direction="column"
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="center"
      style={{ minheight: '100vh' }}>

      <Button variant="contained" startIcon={<AppleIcon/>}
        onClick={loginWithApple}
      >Sign in with apple</Button>

    </Grid>
  )
}
```

My component that calls login:

```
const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser ] = useState(null)
    const [loading, setLoading ] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        return auth.onIdTokenChanged(async(user)=>{
            if(!user){
                console.log('no user');
                setCurrentUser(null);
                setLoading(false)
                return
            }
            const token = await user.getIdToken();
            setCurrentUser(user);
            setLoading(false)
            console.log('token', token);
            console.log('user', user);

        })
    }, [])
    if (!currentUser){
        return <Login/>
    }
    else{
        return <Logout/>
    }
}

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)
```

I also have the scopes added where I configure firebase

```
export const provider = new OAuthProvider('apple.com');
provider.addScope('email')
provider.addScope('name')
```

Comment: You don't have any meaningful code inside your `if (credential) {` branch.

Comment: The tokens are of no use to me as of now they will be used later.

Comment: Email and other claims are in the `id_token`, it’s a JWT.